# how to remove search and label text from link URL in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger, blogs

I want to hide/remove search and label text from the link URL.

[image]

Currently, my URL link is something like : [https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/search/label/CSharp](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/csharp)

I want URL link something like https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/csharp

I also go thought **Custom Redirects** from https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/search/label/CSharp to [https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/csharp](http://coding-vila.blogspot.com/csharp) and its work but when I click on the link it is accessible but still, in the URL it shows old link.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **you can't customize links structure in Blogger**.

Even if you success redirect/rewrite links from **`/search/label/CSharp`** to **`/CSharp`** you should notice that pages with invalid link format will trigger server response with `404 Not Found` in **http header** and this is absolutely harmful for your blog seo.